# What's a good way to catch and report uncaught errors in react apps?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm looking into using cloudwatch RUM to log and report errors in a react single page application. This [blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/using-amazon-cloudwatch-rum-with-a-react-web-application-in-five-steps/) talks about using a React 'Error Boundary', however, Error Boundaries are now listed under '[legacy React APIs](https://react.dev/reference/react/Component#catching-rendering-errors-with-an-error-boundary)' in the official react documentation. Which means they may be removed in the future. What are my alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is "legacy" is the use of Class Components (that include Lifecycle Events).  React is now encouraging everyone to move to Function Components + Hooks.

However as that link shows, there currently is no way to define an Error Boundary using a Function Component (that React offers).  So, my reading of the docs, use of a Class Component as an Error Boundary is just fine.  It is likely that something will change in an upcoming (likely major) release of React.

Alternatively, searching for "error boundary in reactjs" and looking for hits from within the past year, I found [this interesting article](https://blog.logrocket.com/react-error-handling-with-react-error-boundary/) that points to an NPM worth checking out: [react-error-boundary](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-error-boundary).